# how to find telegram embed html-code contains video or image in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, telegram

how to use telegram core API in other environment like browsers

Comment: you can use substr_count or a preg_match .. something along those lines :)

Comment: I didn't change anything in your sample code, just improved your syntax and sentences also capitalized some

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to load "http://t.me/barrtartest1/3" you will get a telegram placeholder page without any content. Afterwards the page loads content by JS.

You should use the link with "?embed=1" get param, for example https://t.me/barrtartest1/3?embed=1

By following the link you will be able to see html with video tag.